# Cannot customize sfGuardGroup - cached version autosfGuardGroup is always used

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel, sfguard

I'm using the sfGuardPlugin with Propel on Symfony 1.4.11. I'm overriding some templates in sfGuardUser as well as sfGuardGroup and sfGuardPermission. On my localhost version this works, but on shared hosting the sfGuardGroup and sfGuardPermission modules stubbornly ignore the templates in my app, reverting instead to the cached autoXXX modules. Curiously the sfGuardUser works in this respect on both platforms.

The debug log is identical until the step

> Call "sfGuardGroupActions->executeIndex()"

The local version continues correctly with

> Render "sf_app_dir/modules/sfGuardGroup/templates/indexSuccess.php"

While the remote server goes on like this:

> Render "sf_root_dir/cache/backend/dev/modules/autoSfGuardGroup/templates/indexSuccess.php"

I have never seen any difference in the behavior of my modules before and this really stumps me. The files in both locations are identical, except the ProjectConfiguration.class.php and database.yml. I haven't found any mention of this kind of problem. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Edit:
Of course I cleared the cache on both ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing!

Notice how autoSfGuardGroup is spelled? When I copied the cached folder I took out the 'auto', leaving a capital 'S' in front of the name. My Mac happily ignored the caps but the hosted server was not so nice.

All is well now.

Maybe I should get new glasses ... 8-}